# Node/Express server randomly skips requests for static files

Tags: node.js, express

I am experiencing a very strange behavior of a node/express server.  From time to time, roughly 1 out of 5 page loads, it randomly refuses to serve one or another static file requested by the page.

The browser fails with the message "[Error] Failed to load resource: The request timed out."  At the same time, express thinks that there simply was no request (see comments in the code below).

I have simplified the code to the point that I don't know what else to comment out, and it is still doing it.  The generated page needs 4 js files from /js and approximately 30 pictures from /img. The total size of all static files is approximately 2MB.  Any one (or several) of those files can be missing.  This can't be related to load and/or memory leaks because it happens on a server without users immediately after restart.

This runs on a Digital Ocean droplet with 512MB ram and their stock MEAN on Ubuntu.  No exceptions are shown.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  console.log(new Date().toString(), e.stack || e);
  process.exit(1);
});



var http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    pagemaker=require('./app/pagemaker').pagemaker; 

    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl/server.key'), 'utf8');
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl/server.crt'), 'utf8');

    var intcert1 = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl/comdom.crt'), 'utf8');
    var intcert2 = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl/comtrust.crt'), 'utf8');
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca:[intcert1, intcert2]};

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// if the browser reports some file as missing, it is also missing in the output of this function!
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.protocol+'://' + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl);
  next();
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img'), {maxAge: 86400000}));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js'), {maxAge: 86400000})); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) { 

   var page=pagemaker('index', 'pt');
   res.set('Content-Type','text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
   res.send(200, page); 

});

app.use(function (req,res) { 
    res.render('404', {url:req.url}); 
});

https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 999; 

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(9877, function(){
  console.log('SSL Express server listening on port 9877');
});
```

Comment: Is it always the same files that are missing every time you retry the request?  Is there a webserver, e.g. nginx that could be intercepting the requests?  Are you sure the requests are pointing to the correct domain and port?

Comment: @takinola: It is always different files. And not every time.  On average, 4 out of 5 page loads are just fine.  When it is not fine, any static file can be missing.  There is no nginx.  Node is connected to 443 through iptables:  `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9877`

Comment: how large are the files?  how many are there?  Is it possible that the timeout occurs because the browser is taking too much time to process all the requests that come before it?

Comment: Nothing that a browser can't handle, about 2MB total.  But I think you are missing the point.  Express thinks that there was no request.  Look at the code above.  The first app.use is a logger.  It is NOT triggered when a file is missing.  When everything goes well, this function prints a complete list of requested files.  When there is a timeout, it actually prints a list containing only delivered files, without the files that timed out.  This makes me think the problem is with express, not the browser.

Comment: I get the problem.  My view is something is happening to the (missing) requests somewhere between the browser and the Express server process.  It could be the request is not being received at all (browser caching, network issues, etc), the request arrives but is ignored (all sockets in use, the request is queued for too long whilst other requests are being processed, etc).  Your code seems to be correct (hence it works 4 out of 5 times) so I am not sure what could be wrong.  BTW, why do you have http.globalAgent.maxSockets at 999?  The default is 5 and I have never had any reason to change it.

Comment: I read in a vaguely related question here on SO that having 999 sockets may help.  It doesn't :(

Comment: I also think that this must be a networking issue either with the machine or node itself, but I desperately lack knowledge in these areas and therefore have no idea where to look.

Comment: If you have access to another machine and/or another network, run the same code and see if you get the same result.  That way you can rule out (or not) machine specific issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently caused by a problem at the Digital Ocean datacenter, not related to my actions.

I diagnosed this by running siege on two identical new droplets in different datacenters. Both were in default configuration running the sample MEAN app.  The one in Amsterdam (where my original droplet is) had the same problem, the one in London was working perfectly fine.

As I was preparing to file a ticket, the sneaky bastards fixed something and now the problem is gone.

Cost me 3 days.  Thank you, DO!